# k-mers in a string with no spaces

Tags: java

I am wondering what is the best way in Java to partition a long string with no spaces into k-mers. Basically I am thinking about testing with different sizes of k-mers and count the number and exact location of repeats of a given k-mer in the original string.

My question is relative to the approach to do, sliding window ? hashmap ?
In your opinion what is the best way of doing that task ?

Also there is the concept here of overlapping k-mers that I dont know how to deal with, if someone could point me to the right approach it would be great.

Thanks in advance
Dar

Comment: A _k-mer_ is some known substring repeated _k_ times?

Comment: Or one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-mer)?

Comment: Yes K-mer is let's say a word with different repeated instances on the string

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is about. Do you want to divide a given string in smaller parts (k-mers)? If that's the case it would be helpful for people trying to answer if you could give an example of a long string and your desired outcome.